# How do I tell how many lines of a specific face fit in a window?

Tags: window, faces

I'm making a presentation mode where I want to vertically center some text in the window, which is the only window in the frame. I'm using a custom face so I can control how large the font is.

To horizontally center the text, I can use [`window-max-chars-per-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html#index-window_002dmax_002dchars_002dper_002dline) with the `face` argument, so I can get the number of characters put in a line.

But I also want to know how many lines are in the window. There's [`window-body-height`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html#index-window_002dbody_002dheight), but that doesn't let me specify a face.

How can I tell how tall a window is in lines of a specific face?

Comment: Maybe you can use `font-info` and `(window-body-height nil t)`?

Comment: Hrm, thanks! It looks like I can do something based off `window-font-height`. I'll look into it more and see if I can make it work. Thanks for the pointer towards looking into the font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can get how many pixels tall a face is with `window-font-height`, and how many pixels tall a window is with `window-body-height`. From there it's a simple division with truncating.

```
(defun zck--lines-in-window (face &optional window)
  "Calculate how many lines of text with face FACE can fit in WINDOW."
  (truncate (window-body-height window t)
            (window-font-height window face)))
```

Comment: If you are waiting for better answers add some notice about that to this one otherwise accept this one please to mark the question  as done. Have fun,

Comment: I can't accept my own answer until 24 hours after I posted it, but I'm planning on doing so unless there's a flaw in this answer. Thanks for the suggestion to look into fonts and `window-body-height`!